# Initialise, for loop and append in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

In raw python we can do this:

```
new_list = []
for index in range(3):

    new_values = list(range(index, 3 + index))
    new_list.append(values)

print(new_list)
# [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

How can we do this in Scipy with sparse matrices?

Comment: 'does not seem to work' is the wrong way to describe a problem. We like real errors.  Also why are you using `sparse.hstack`?

Comment: Both the numpy and sparse versions of `stack` create a new array/matrix from a **list** of arrays.    Doing that kind of stacking iteratively is inefficient, requiring a full copy each time.  Stick with the list append, and do your array construction once, at the end.

Comment: Ok I see your point @hpaulj - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea of using `hstack` and you can indeed do this in a slightly simpler way using the `numpy` version of `hstack`. In most circumstances, `numpy` accepts array-**like** objects. So in your case, we can just use the list that you are trying to append inside of `hstack`. See the new code:

```py
import numpy as np

new_list = np.array([])
for index in range(3):

    new_values = list(range(index, 3 + index))
    new_list = np.hstack([new_list, new_values])

print(new_list)
# [0. 1. 2. 1. 2. 3. 2. 3. 4.]
```

If you want a separate dimension for each list you are appending, you can use `np.vstack` along with initializing your `new_list` array as 2D. Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np

new_list = np.empty((0, 3))
for index in range(3):

    new_values = list(range(index, 3 + index))

    new_list = np.vstack([new_list, new_values])

print(new_list)
# [[0. 1. 2.]
#  [1. 2. 3.]
#  [2. 3. 4.]]
```

Here is an example for performing the same thing using strings instead.

```py
import numpy as np
import string

new_list = np.empty((0, 3))
for index in range(3):

    new_values = [string.ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(index, 3 + index)]
    new_list = np.vstack([new_list, new_values])

print(new_list)
# [['a' 'b' 'c']
#  ['b' 'c' 'd']
#  ['c' 'd' 'e']]
```

Comment: @Outcast, I've added another solution that probably matches what you were looking for.

Comment: Ok and what do I have to specify more with strings?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify anything more for strings. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: repeated stack in a loop is inefficient.  Stick with the list append.